# appendChild not working and showing error

Tags: javascript

I have a js which is showing error in javascript console **Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null** in this file:

```
(function(d) {
    if( typeof jQuery === 'undefined' ) {
        var srsr = d.createElement('script');
        srsr.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js';
        d.body.appendChild(srsr);

        setTimeout(function(){ doThat(); }, 5000);
    } else {
        doThat();
    }


    function getHost( url ) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        var host = a.hostname;

        var t = host.split(".");
        if( t.length == 2 ) {
            var host = "www."+host;
        } 

        return host;
    }   

    function doThat() {
        $.ajax({
            url:    'http://mobilesplashpro.com/app/assets/php/tRaCk_loAdInG_PoPUp.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'adrs='+getHost( document.domain ),
            dataType:   'jsonp',
            jsonp:  false,
            jsonpCallback: 'methodCallback',
            success: function( data ) {
                if( data.message == "yes" ) {
                    $.getScript("http://mobilesplashpro.com/app/assets/js/popup/PoPUp_txt_CoDE.js",function() { iPhoneAlert(); });
                } else {

                }
            }, 
            error: function( error ) {
                console.log( error ); 
            }
        });
    }

})( document );
```

have used Appendchild code in another file which is working perfectly but not in it..

Thanks

Comment: check what are you getting in d, looks like d.body is null

Comment: What browser are you running this in?

Comment: To work, this snippet should be placed in the `body`, if it's in the `head`, the `body` won't exist at the time the code is executed.

Comment: @Teemu: Or another solution could be to use `d.head`, possibly.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu it works perfectly..but not sure why its working for another files in head

Comment: @AryanSareen Hard to say without seeing the code, but maybe it's not in an IIFE, or is executed within `$(document).ready()` or after `window.onload` has been fired. What ever it was, the function is executed at the time when `body` exists on that other page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, place this code in the end of your body (if this is in your head, the body doest not exists), if you must place it in the head, you should make some sort of interval untill you simulated a DomReady event (That garantees you have a document.body to traverse).

Example:

```
var intervalDomReady = setInterval(function() { 
    if (document.body) {     
        clearInterval(intervalDomReady);
        intervalDomReady =null;
        DomReady(); 
    }
},500);

function DomReady() { /*you code*/ }
```

You only have the reference to jquery from google CDN once it is loaded. So you will not have sure that It will happen in 5 secs, must first bind to the onload event of the script an then try to use jquery functions.

Example of solution:

```
var d = document;
var srsr = d.createElement('script');
srsr.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js';
srsr.src.onload = function() { doThat(); }
```

Comment: The function is being called with `document`, not an iframe.  That's shown in the linked JS file.

Comment: but m using the appendchild function in another file and its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is running when the document loads, it's a valid use-case for `document.write`.

It'll also simplify things if you use `document.write` to load the script, since it'll load the script synchronously.

As a result, you would eliminate the need for the `doThat()` function, and the `setTimeout`.

---

So first put your jQuery check and script loading code in a separate script at the top...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if( typeof jQuery === 'undefined' ) {
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"><\/scr' + 'ipt>');
}
</script>
```

Then put your main script in a separate script below the one above...

```
<script>
(function(d) {
    function getHost( url ) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        var host = a.hostname;

        var t = host.split(".");
        if( t.length == 2 ) {
            var host = "www."+host;
        } 
        return host;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url:    'http://mobilesplashpro.com/app/assets/php/tRaCk_loAdInG_PoPUp.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'adrs='+getHost( document.domain ),
        dataType:   'jsonp',
        jsonp:  false,
        jsonpCallback: 'methodCallback',
        success: function( data ) {
            if( data.message == "yes" ) {
                $.getScript("http://mobilesplashpro.com/app/assets/js/popup/PoPUp_txt_CoDE.js",function() { iPhoneAlert(); });
            } else {

            }
        }, 
        error: function( error ) {
            console.log( error ); 
        }
    });
})( document );
</script>
```

Now if jQuery isn't loaded, the new script will be written and loaded below the first, and above the second, and we never had to perform any sort of DOM selection.

Comment: Good point in the document.write syncronous approach, I didnt even know that. Consering you already have a document.body html, does this replace all our html ?

Comment: @Roger: No. If `document.write` is use during the initial page load, then the HTML is written inline after the current script, which reminds me of an error in my answer. The code that uses the loaded script would need to be in a separate script so that the loaded script can be written first. I'll update.